# What sources of information are there available to follow news about Bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain-fork, news-coverage

What sources of information are there where you can follow possible changes, announcements of forks, protocol updates etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend 2 sources:

1. [blog.blockchain.com](https://blog.blockchain.com/)
2. [www.coindesk.com](https://www.coindesk.com/)

If it is being talked about elsewhere, it will be made visible here.

Comment: blockchain.com is horrible in all ways: they have a long history of terrible cryptographic and other money losing bugs. And now they're endangering your coins by muddying the very definition of Bitcoin and willy nilly hard forking it off against.

Answer (score 2):

Since Bitcoin is decentralized, everybody claiming to be an authority is highly suspect. One early site is still going strong in providing independent practical (pro-Bitcoin) information:

https://www.bitcoin.org

Make sure to stay away .com variant!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a polarising answer but also be sure to check out reddit - [r/bitcoin](http://www.reddit.com/r/bitcoin) If you sift through all the moon memes, you can find some useful information and links.